# Can i still use my asus x556uj laptop if i remove my internal battery?

Tags: asus-laptop

Hi I think my battery is kinda bloating up and i think i need to remove it just to be safe. The replacement battery needs time to be delivered. Can i turn the laptop on without the battery? The model is Asus x556uj

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Any laptop can run with only the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

Havn't seen a laptop, that wouldn't work while plugged into the socket with the battery removed.

I do work in IT, but have mostly dealt with HP, Dell, MSI, Acer hardware. with all of those it has worked.

Better remove that bloated battery, before it burns a whole through the laptop anyway.

Look at it this way:  when all is good, the laptop is charging to 100%, the internal curcit knows where it has to divert the power. Meaning: when the battery is unplugged, it pushes the power directly to the mainboard. (simply speaking)

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

as long as you're connected to a power supply of course then yes it'll function just like a Desktop, no need for the battery.

On the HP forum, there was a response from an "HP Expert" that said it's actually better to run the laptop that way as then the battery isn't getting unnecessary charge.